# Wcf call from Android using ksoap2: Requests couldn't be logged

Tags: c#, android, wcf, ksoap2

I want to log all requests comes to my Wcf service. I am looking logs using **Service Trace Tool**. I can log everything (requests and responses) if the service called using **WcfTestClient**. But I can't see any request from Android. (But responses to Android shown.)

**Why Android requests doesn't shown? Where are they going?**

My **Web.config** file contains this section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" >
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener"
                         name="Default" >
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add initializeData="D:\logs\TodesService.svclog"
                         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                         name="messages" >
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true" >
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener"
                         name="Default" >
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" >
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        ...
</system.diagnostics>
```